# Can a UIViewImage draw its image outside its frame?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

When making a photo viewer app found that our UIImageView controller is drawing its image outside its frame when the content mode is different neither ScaleToFill nor Aspect Fit.

Trying to understand why; I isolated the problem making a new project which only has a UIImageView with the following frame (50,50,100,100). The image size contained in it is (4592,3056).

After running the app, with the content mode set to ScaleToFill and AspectFit it all worked as expected:

But after setting the contentMode of the UIImageView to TopLeft, the image is drawn outside its frame, the odd thing is that the log from the frame after all has been drawn is still the original {50,50,100,100}.

I've try to understand the issue by moving the Autoresize, the clips and the content mode of the UIViewController but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried `view.clipToBounds=YES`?

Answer (score 2):

set clipToBounds = YES on the view.

its NO by default because that makes drawing way cheaper

Comment: Yes I will, just wanted to know what was happening.. I'm trying to understand the ScrollView with an UIImageView...